# Como contar os espaços de uma String em java

Tags: java

Aqui seguei o exemplo do codigo que estava fazendo:

```
package manipulacaos;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ManipulacaoS {
    public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

     String letra = "a";
     String s;
     int Ccount=0;
     int spacecount=0;


        System.out.println("Digite a String que quer informações..: ");
        s = ler.next();


        for( int i=0; i<s.length(); ){
            Ccount++;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Essa palavra possui.: "+Ccount+" Caracteres.");

       for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ){
         if( s.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
          spacecount++;
        }
     }
        System.out.println("Essa palavra possui..: "+spacecount+" espacos.");

        int quantidade = s.length() - s.replaceAll(letra, "").length();
        System.out.println("Número de ocorrências da letra '" + letra + "': " + quantidade);
    }
    }
```

Comment: coloquei ele todo agr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com o seu código, exceto por estar usando [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) ao invés de [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--). O primeiro consegue ler a entrada até que haja um espaço, ou seja, você não consegue ler uma string "inteira" que tenha um espaço no meio (`João Paulo` = `João`). Já o [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) irá ler toda a linha, mesmo com espaços no meio, até encontrar `\n` (`João Paulo` = `João Paulo`).

Ou seja, quando você tenta contar os espaços ele retorna `0` justamente por não haver nenhum, está correto. Se quer que seja considerada toda a linha, basta trocar os [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) do seu código por [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).

`next` faz a leitura e mantêm o cursor na mesma linha.
`nextLine` faz a leitura e posiciona o cursor na linha seguinte.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo, sabia q tava faltando algo kk obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
String s = "Conte os espaços desta String   ";
 for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ){
  if( s.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
   count++;
 }
}
```

Comment: testei separado e deu certo , mas quando testo junto com os outros codigos não aparece o numero de espaços

Comment: só funciona se a variavel ja for definida  como a sua s, mas se o usuario digitar não conta os espaços e conta so os caracteres antes do espaço